# How to get get all form's input fields of the type text, password, file, textarea and selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can get all the input fields of a specific type within a form with the help of `jQuery`.

```
jQuery("#signup-form").find('input').each(function(index, element) {

});
```

I know I can get text boxes by:

```
jQuery("#signup-form").find('input[type="text"]');
```

How to get get all form's input fields of the type text, password, file, textarea and selectbox? With a selector or a regular expression?

Comment: Are you talking about the :input selector? http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine selectors in a single expression:

```
find('input:text, input[type=password], select, textarea')
```

Note `input:text` instead of `input[type=text]`, as the latter won't find `input` tags with no explicit type (which *default* to `text`).

```js
 jQuery('#signup-form').
   find('input:text, input[type=password], select, textarea').
   css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signup-form">
  <input type="text" value="this" />
  <input value="also this" />
  <input type="password" value="stars" />
  <button>not this</button>
  <textarea>this, though</textarea>
  <select><option>and this</option></select> 
</form>
```

Comment: excellent code Paul and explanation as well. like your code snippet as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use comma like on a normal selector like:

```
.find('input[type=text], input[type=password]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple selector:

```
jQuery('#signup-form input[type=text]').each(function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); });
```

You can use attributes to specify type or whatever.  `find` isn't really appropriate to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = jQuery(":input");
```

`inputs` will be an array containing all inputs elements.